# Django: how to get username in template using django-tweaks

Tags: django, django-templates, django-widget-tweaks

I have rendered a html form with `widget_tweak`s and i want the default value of the field to be the current username.

```
  #template
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <form method="post">
  {% render_field form.title value="{{ request.user }}" readonly="True" %}
  </form>
  {% else %}
  <h 1>Login First</h 1>
  {% endif %}
```

but this render the exact text `"{{ request.user }}"` rather than printing the username. If I use the

tag and use the `{{ request.user }}`, prints the current username.

This is how my `views.py` looks:

## views.py

```
class CreatePostView(CreateView):
template_name = 'posts/new_post.html'
redirect_field_name = 'posts/post_detail.html'
form_class = PostForm
model = Post
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('posts:post_detail', args = [self.id])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `django` templatetags, you do not need double accolades `{{ }}`. Try the following:

```html
<!-- Your template -->
[...]
{% render_field form.title value=request.user readonly="True" %}
[...]
```

I just removed the double accolades.

Comment: @Kunal glad to hear that! Do not hesitate to upvote and accept my answer, so your question can be closed.

Comment: Completely forgot bout that